# Script to create a log file and send an email

Tags: command-line, mail

```
#!/bin/bash

who>log.txt

top>>log.txt

EMAIL="yasni.exe@gmail.com"
LOG="/home/projekt/skrypt/log.txt"

mail -s "skrypt_logi" ${EMAIL}<${LOG}

rm logi.txt
```

I installed package for using email, scrit create log.txt, put some information in log.txt, but doesn't send email and it hangs so I have to interrupt it.

Comment: It is probably getting stuck on the top command.  Maybe try changing that line to `top -n 1 >> log.txt`.  That way top does 1 iteration at that moment.

Comment: Have you configured and tested your mail package? Can you send a test message to your mail address?

Answer (score 0):

You create "log.txt" in whatever your **current** directory is, but then you specify the full path when you want to read from it.

You should use your variable throughout the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
email="yasni.exe@gmail.com"
log="/home/projekt/skrypt/log.txt"

who > "$log"
top -n1 >> "$log"

mail -s "skrypt_logi" "$email" < "$log"

rm "$log"
```

Read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667) about the importance of quoting your variables.

Comment: Now it seems like script works (do not stuck in command line), but it still doesnt send email and do not delete log file after sendign email

Comment: @Frubergos as for your answer that wasn't an answer ... I checked this script on my server .. yes it works ... the reason it probably doesn't work for you is because you probably don't have sendmail set up or something ... so it doesn't know "how" to send a email.  I also tried it on my system where I don't have sendmail set up .. I get an error ` line 8: mail: command not found` so this is probably why its not emailing to you or deleting the log because it crashes at line 8

Comment: @Frubergos if you arent seeing an error .. run the command .. of course make sure its executable `chmod +x /pathtoscript/scriptname` check `/var/log/syslog` and see if it prints an error about `line 8`

Answer (score 0):

Script stuck because of command 'top'. It should be like that:

```
top -b -n1 >> log.tx
```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/top.1.html

```
   -b  :Batch-mode operation
        Starts top in Batch mode, which could be useful  for  sending
        output  from  top  to  other  programs or to a file.  In this
        mode, top will not accept input and runs until the iterations
        limit  you've  set with the `-n' command-line option or until
        killed.
```